# Is this a reasonable way for choosing a certain index from a list by considering the elements of a corresponding list in python?

Tags: python, list

I am relatively new to programming, and have this problem:

There are two lists: C=[i,i,k,l,i] and D =[m,n,o,p,q]

I want to select the index of the minimum element of C. If k or l is the minimum, it is quite simple, since the min function will directly return the desired index. But if i is the minimum, there are several possibilities. In that case, I want to look at list D's elements, but only at the indices where i occurs in C. I then want to chose my sought-after index based on the minimum of those particular elements in D

I thought of the following code:

```
min_C = min(C)
if C.count(min_C) == 1:
    soughtafter_index = C.index(min_C)
else:
    possible_D_value = []
    for iterate in C:
        if iterate==min_C:
            possible_index = C.index(iterate)
            possible_D_value.append(D[possible_index])
     best_D_value = min(possible_D_value)
     soughtafter_index = D.index(best_D_value)
```

(Note that in the problem C and D will always have the same length)

I havent had a chance to test the code yet, but wanted to ask whether it is reasonable? Is there a better way to handle this? (and what if there is a third list-- then this code will get even longer...)

Thank you all

Comment: I want the index so that I can use it to get the elements from yet another list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
soughtafter_index = list(zip(C, D)).index(min(zip(C,D)))
```

UPDATE with the required explanation:

```
>>> C = [1, 5, 1, 3, 1, 4]
>>> D = [0, 1, 1, 3, 0, 1]
>>> list(zip(C, D))
[(1, 0), (5, 1), (1, 1), (3, 3), (1, 0), (4, 1)]
>>> min(zip(C, D))
(1, 0)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Wow read more about zip, it is quite powerful!